# How can I get rid of brackets in "Thread"?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
{Thread[{a, b} -> {1, 2}], c -> 10}
```

> {{a -> 1, b -> 2}, c -> 10}

**How can I get rid of the inner brackets ?**
*I tried:*

```
{Flatten[Thread[{a, b} -> {1, 2}]], c -> 10}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: It should have been `Flatten[{Thread[{a, b} -> {1, 2}], c -> 10}]`.

Comment: @J. M. Yes,that works !  thank you very much!

Comment: Can't use `Thread[{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 10}]` or `Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> {1, 2, 10, 20}]`

Comment: You can use `Append`, `Flatten` or `Join` (all of which have specific uses), but also following construct works if you want a list to be merged on middle of another: `Sequence @@ Thread[{a, b} -> {1, 2}]]`

Answer (score 4):

This will do the job:

```
Append[Thread[{a, b} -> {1, 2}], c -> 10]
```

Comment: Hmm... yes, it works for c-> 10, but if you have more variables , like:  `Append[Thread[{a, b} -> pair], {c -> 10, d -> 20}]`; it does not work

Comment: `Join @@ {Thread[{a, b} -> {1, 2}], {c -> 10, d -> 20}}`